# UFT error: Cannot identify the object

Tags: object, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I'm using Unified Functional Testing v12.02 (or QTP).

Sometimes while running script i get the below error and sometimes I don't.

> Cannot identify the object "..." (of class ...) Verify that this
>   object's properties match an object currently displayed in your
>   application.
>
> Tip: If the objects in your application have changed, the Maintenance
>   Run Mode can help you identify and update your steps and/or the
>   objects in your repository.

I checked OR and the object itself with Spy tool and they have the same properties.

Sometimes I get the same error in other objects, but if I run again the script it works well.

Can someone explain me what might be the problem?
Im a little bit confused why sometimes i get these errors and sometimes don't.

I'm testing a simple web application (for training purposes)

Also I'm using the following add-ins: Web, Web-SAPUI5, Visual Basic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly object wont be in the readystate. Check State of the Object using

```
Webedit(googlesearch).object.readyState="complete"
Webedit(googlesearch).object.Load
Webedit(googlesearch).object.Disabled=False
```

Comment: Should i use if statement to check all the objects in my form?

Comment: Yes indeed . If object identifies after certain minute . Then Use Waitproperty statement also